# How to ASP.NET Site and SQL Mirroring

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to implement a SQL Mirroring to help an ASP.NET Site to rely on backup server in case something happens to Main Server, I have already gone through few of the questions related to this subject and most were answers for specific questions or issues they have.

Following summarize what I am trying to do and please help me / guide me if I am in right path.

1. We have a Busy Server running an ASP.NET WebApplication
2. Web Application uses Two Database ASP.NET FORMS DB and custom database for storing custom data.
3. Now we are planning to set a new server that will serve as a backup in case main fails
4. Proposed solution I am thinking about is as follows.
5. Two Servers both will host ASP.NET WebApplication, Both has SQL Server that has the Database Deployed (with the Latest
6. Now one server will act as primary and Push changes to other SQL server.

Now the Questions :

1. is My approach Right ?
2. In case if Main Server Fails and Other Database Takes up, later once the main servers comes up do the changes from Secondary servers synced to main server ?
3. Can I have a Load balancer Configured so that on high Load we will have request load balanced between these two Servers ? will database sync ?

Any pointers ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer for your first question: no, you need one ASP.Net web-server with [appropriate connections string to principal and mirror database](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005), but your mirroring must be in automatic-failover mode.

When you use the [mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx), you have two servers (we will not speak about witness server for simplicity). First one has the database that working and accessible for users (Principal), second one has the Mirror database. This database is not accessible for read or write (one exception: you can create the SNAPSHOT from this database, but it is not your case), this database is in restoring state, because this server applies the transactions from Principal.

so, answer for your third question is - no, you cannot use the second server for load-balancing.

When the witness-server (if you use the automatic failover) checks that Principal database isn't accessible, he gives the command to recovery the mirror database. This database is accessible now, and if you use the connection string to use the mirroring (see the examples [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005)), clinets will connect to this server instead of failed principal server. If you will use mirroring without automatic-failover, you need to recover the mirrored database and redirect the connections by your hands. After that synchronization will be lost. In this case you need to set up the mirroring again when you need.